# JasperReports - How to deal with nested object collection

Tags: jasper-reports, nested-loops

I'm Java developer for about 2 years but I'm new with Jasper so I need some help, I know how to deal with a simple report with fields coming from a class or entity but now I have to do something harder.

I have these 3 entities:

Group 
Function
Privilege

The group may have a list of function, and a function has a list oc privileges, that is the simplest scenario but a group may have a list of other groups instead of a list of function.

simple example: Group1 -> (Function1 [Privilege1, Privilege2], Function2 [Privilege3, Privilege4] - Group1 got a list with 2 functions each one with 2 privileges.

complex example: Group2 -> (Group1 -> [Function1 {Privilege1, Privilege2}, Function2 {Privilege3, Privilege4}], Group3 -> [FunctionX {Privilege1, Privilege2}, FunctionY... - Group 2 got a list with 2 sub-groups, each sub-group got functions and so on.

To build the report I'm used to send to Jasper just one object, in this case the parent group so I believe I need a way to iterate through its lists but I don't know what is the best approach.

I made some research about groups and sub reports but I couldn't find any situation like that and I can't figure out what is the best for what I need to do.

Some help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm create jasper report as pass one single object as parameter or field.
assume one file structure

com.project.MyClass, we pass object of MyClass
this object is passed as parameter or as datasource whatever you want.

assume myClass is object

if you pass one single object than you must change expression class java.lang.String to com.project.MyClass in jasper.

now you can access your object as $F{myClass }.getMethodName()

you can also use use $F{myClass }.getMethodName().getSubmethodName()

this is 100% working. I use it for my all reports. If you want any help then ask.